# Four particles arranged in a square and rotated on a turntable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A question reads.

> Four particles, each of mass 3kg, are connected by light, inextensible strings, each 0.08m long, so that they form a square with the particles at the corners and the strings forming the sides. The particles are placed in this configuration symmetrically on a smooth turntable, which is made to rotate with angular speed 2 rad s^-1. Find the tension in the strings.

The answer given to this question is 0.48N, but I can't work out why that is the correct answer.
I can get the value of 0.48 by taking a radius of 0.04m, then acceleration = ${\omega^2} * radius = 0.16 m s^{-2}$, leading to F = ma = 0.48N, but I don't understand how the radius of the circular path is 0.04m.

Surely if the particles are each at a corner of the circle, the distance between them and the centre of the turntable is $\sqrt{2*(0.04)^2} = \sqrt2/25$.

What am I missing/doing wrong in attempting to solve this question.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings have length d=0.08 m, then the distance from the center to each mass is $r=d/\sqrt{2}=0.056$ m, which you have noted yourself.
The centripetal force is $F_c=m\omega^2r=0.678$ N. But the centripetal force vector is the sum of the tensile force vectors of the two strings, each of which is at 45 deg. Therefore, you have to divide $F_c$ by $\sqrt 2$ to get the tensile force.

Comment: Thank you. I had found the centripetal force, but I couldn't work out how to get the tension from it.